# pgfplots different axis scaling in one diagram

Tags: pgfplots

So I'm trying to create a plot where let's say the y axis is scaled in 2 per cm above the value 2 and in 0.4 below the value 2. In other words I want to stretch the plot in an area. I'm not talking about just changing the ticks but to also stretch the plot in that area.

Something like below, obviously in standard pgfplots-style.

[image]

I'll give you the plot I'm trying to locally stretch, I only want to stretch the negative y-axis portion (so the plot doesn't hug the x-axis there).

```
\documentclass[11pt,
paper=a4,                   
footinclude,
oneside
]{scrbook}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[european]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
          axis lines = middle,
          ticks = none,
          xlabel = ${U}$,
          ylabel = ${I}$,
          width = 11cm,
          height = 8cm,
          ylabel style={at=(rotate = -90},
          every axis x label/.style={
            at={(ticklabel* cs:1.0)},
            anchor=west,
          },
          every axis y label/.style={
            at={(ticklabel* cs:1.0)},
            anchor=south,
          },
          xmin = -0.5,
          xmax = 0.8,
          ymin = -1,
          %ymax = 2,
        ]

        \addplot[
          domain = -0.25:0.69,
          samples = 100,
          thick,
          color = blue,
        ]
        gnuplot{
          0.00000000001 * (exp(x/(0.026)) - 1)                  
        }
        node[left, pos = 0.9]{$I_D$}
        ;


        \addplot[
          domain = -0.5:-0.3,
          samples = 40,
          thick,
          color = blue,
        ]
        gnuplot{
          -0.000000001118 * exp(-41.005 * x)                  
        }
        ;

        \draw[color = blue]
        (axis cs: -0.2,0.5)
        node[]{$I_S(U < 0) \neq 0$}
        ;

        \draw[thick, color = blue,]
        (axis cs: -0.25,0.1)
        --
        (axis cs: -0.25,-0.1)
        ;

        \draw[thick, color = blue,]
        (axis cs: -0.3,0.1)
        --
        (axis cs: -0.3,-0.1)
        ;

        %\draw[dashed]
        %(axis cs: 0.6,0)
        %(axis cs: 0.6,
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{center}
  \caption{}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

All I've found so far was how to transform the whole axis but not just portions.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? It would be highly confusing to read such a plot in my opinion. What you can do is plot the absolute values on a logarithmic scale. Then you can see equal detail at all y values. Or you can create a inset.

Comment: See  tex.stackexchange.com/questions/359878/